# how to use both where clause and group_concat in single table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

```
select `Part Name` ,`Current Status` as `Current Status`,
group_concat(`Inward Qty`) as `Inward Qty` from production 
where `Current Status` = 'Active' group by `Manufacturer Part Number`;
```

I have been try to group_concat the value which have been already
using the where clause in mysql ,can any one help with this query.

I was expecting this answer

```
Part Name      Current Status     Inward Qty
    
ADAPTOR         Active      25,6,10,10,20,0
BATTERY         Active      0,730
BATTERY         Active      50,30,0
BATTERY         Active      0,1,25,10,3
BATTERY         Active      50,10,10,4,0,500,10,30,83
BATTERY CHARGER Active      30,0,1
BATTERY-STRAP   Active      100,0,1000,5,1000
BATTERY-STRAP   Active      0,509
BATTERY-STRAP   Active      1000,1000,5,0,100
BM-IC           Active      0,9,40,40,100
```

But i am getting this

```
Part Name      Current Status     Inward Qty

ADAPTOR         Active              0
BATTERY         Active              0
BATTERY         Active              0
BATTERY         Active              0
BATTERY         Active              0
BATTERY CHARGER Active              0
BATTERY-STRAP   Active              0
BATTERY-STRAP   Active              0
BATTERY-STRAP   Active              0
BM-IC           Active              0
```

Comment: please share sample data script

Comment: Can't understands your Question Amit Verma